# Confused with attachment mimetype order

Tags: attachments

Suppose I have attachments of MIME type `image/png`, `image/jpeg` and `image/gif`. And I have template files `image.php` and `gif.php` in my theme folder. So, this means that I want to customize a page displaying content of `text/gif` MIME type. Let's assume that `attachment.php` is used for displaying the rest of the MIME types and I can't use it for `image/everything_except_gif`. But the application will never get to the `gif.php` file (or `image_gif.php`) even though it describes a more specific case than `image.php`.

Now, if we look at taxonomies, everything works correctly. File `taxonomy-sometax-term8.php` will be used instead of `taxonomy-sometax.php`, because it describes a more specific case.

I did a search and found a suggestion to create a plugin, but why not make other query types behave the way attachments do and have us writing plugins for taxonomy/category/page/everything_else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this does seem like a lapse in template hierarchy.

The easiest for case described would probably be handling logic in `image.php`, along the lines of (see [`get_attachment_template()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_attachment_template/) for mime type retrieval):

```
if( 'gif' === $subtype ) {

    include 'gif.php';
}
else {

    // generic image template
}
```

For more complicated logic it might be worth just ignoring native order and overriding it with custom one for this branch of hierarchy.